# Swap date fields when one date is less than the other

Tags: t-sql, sql-update

I am attempting to flip date fields as for some reason the people who sent the data to us has them in the wrong fields.  Essentially whenever revived_date is greater than JDate they need to be flipped around.  I attempted the code below and it said it corrects 2341 fields and then I run a select and it shows no records found but when looking at the data I clearly see wrong data.

```
UPDATE defendants_ALL_backup
SET JDate = revived_date, revived_date = JDate
WHERE convert(varchar,JDate, 101) < convert(varchar, revived_date, 101);
```

If I select the top 1000 rows the first 3 are wrong and look like this so it obviously doesn't work.

```
     JDate                   revived_date
2011-04-14 00:00:00.000 1986-02-11 00:00:00.000
2011-04-14 00:00:00.000 1986-02-11 00:00:00.000
2011-04-14 00:00:00.000 1986-02-11 00:00:00.000
```

Any ideas?

Comment: why are you converting them to varchar in order to do the comparison?  Dates have an inherent order.

Comment: Have you got some `id` as table column, too?

Comment: @StuartAinsworth I converted to varchar based on something I read and because the other way didn't work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you have uniqnue ID and the first date should be smaller then the second one:

```
DECLARE @DataSource TABLE
(
    [ID] TINYINT
   ,[DateOne] DATETIME2
   ,[DateTwo] DATETIME2
)

INSERT INTO @DataSource ([ID], [DateOne], [DateTwo])
VALUES (1, '1986-02-11 00:00:00.000', '2011-04-14 00:00:00.000')
      ,(2, '2013-02-11 00:00:00.000', '2011-04-14 00:00:00.000')
      ,(3, '2012-02-11 00:00:00.000', '2011-04-14 00:00:00.000')
      ,(4, '2011-05-11 00:00:00.000', '2011-04-14 00:00:00.000')
      ,(5, '1986-02-11 00:00:00.000', '2011-04-14 00:00:00.000')

;WITH DataForFix ([ID], [DateOne], [DateTwo]) AS
(
    SELECT [ID]
          ,[DateOne]
          ,[DateTwo]
    FROM @DataSource
    WHERE [DateOne] > [DateTwo]
)
UPDATE @DataSource 
SET [DateOne] = DFF.[DateTwo]
   ,[DateTwo] = DFF.[DateOne]
FROM @DataSource DS
INNER JOIN DataForFix DFF
    ON DS.[ID] = DFF.[ID]

SELECT [ID]
      ,[DateOne]
      ,[DateTwo]
FROM @DataSource
```

Comment: Perfect thank you.  I was assuming that I could do it without using a separate table based on what I read.  Guess they and I were wrong.

Answer (score 1):

In the three example rows you have listed, the JDate is already greater than the revived_date, so those records would not have be swapped because of your WHERE clause.

You are comparing to varchars, which will to a comparison alphabetically. If you are wanting to compare the values as dates, they don't need to be converted to anything else

```
UPDATE defendants_ALL_backup
SET JDate = revived_date, revived_date = JDate
WHERE JDate < revived_date
```

Comment: Oops fixed. Still doesn't work that way either I copied the wrong query.